# XBMC crash after selecting "play". Ubuntu 14.04 and 13.0 gotham. Link to crashlog

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, radeon, amd, xbmc

I have a brand new machine with fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to run Gotham 13.0 on it. I've already added the restricted multimedia codecs (just in case) to Ubuntu.

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

As well as Unrestricted LibavCodec

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra
```

My graphics is AMD/ATI Tahiti (Radeon HD 7970) with a core i7.

Here's the XBMC crashlog: http://xbmclogs.com/show.php?id=209365

Here's what's happening: I just download the appropriate PPA's etc. through the XBMC wiki.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install xbmc
```

The first time I installed it on this machine, I went through installed Fusion and ran the Hub wizard Template/Setup. Everythings seems good,
but when I select Al Jazeera, for example, I click "watch live", and then I get the "working" scroll in the bottom right for few seconds, and then the entire program force closes. The same happens with " The Daily Show" "Youtube" "UsTv Now" etc.
I completly uninstalled XBMC

```
sudo apt-get purge xbmc xbmc-standalone
```

and started over. This time only installing one add on and trying it out. Still I get the same results. The music add-ons work though. I have this posted a few days on XBMC forums, and no replies yet. I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu or XBMC issue ,at this point. 
[image]

Comment: Did you look out if there are bugs about this?

Comment: I'm finding bug reports for screen tearing,  but I haven't gotten to that point yet.  I can't find any reports for crash on streaming start up.

Answer (score 0):

It's a driver issue, install the new omega drivers, that solved the problem for me and I run a dual hd7970 and had the same issue until the driver update, so its the ability of the driver not the card its self and trust me this will solve the issue and will also allow you to do more with your card.